# Bootstrap 4 fixed column collapses if contains long text & messes up responsive hiding

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm going crazy over this and I can't seem to find out why this happens. I'm not so advanced with bootstrap but I think it's ok and I already tried many different ways.

So I have a chat box inside of a card, with one column that should try to take the whole card width, and on the right side a col-2 with list of users that disappears on smaller screens (`d-none d-lg-block`)
The messages are stacked in per-user blocks, just like in Discord.
Each message block consists of a col-xs-1 that holds the users avatar, and then a fulll-width column for actual messages.

While everything seems to be okay, the messages column somehow collapses under the avatar column on smaller screens when one of the messages is long.
It also causes problems with the responsive users column, before hitting the d-none breakpoint, it gets pushed under the other fixed width column. When a message is very long, it gets pushed there anyway on all screen sizes. I tried word-break, overflows etc without any luck. The word is broken into pieces yet it still causes problems.

You can view the code on bootply: https://www.bootply.com/KmwTGY86yu
Or as a snippet

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Card header
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <!-- full-width column for message box -->
              <div class="container-fluid" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden">
                <!-- start of messages box -->
                <div class="row">
                  <!-- message block -->
                  <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <div style="height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: black"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <h5 class="text-danger float-left">Username</h5>
                    <small class="text-muted float-right">timestamp</small>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div>
                      This is a single message
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      This is another single message
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <hr class="w-100">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <div style="height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: black"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <h5 class="text-danger float-left">Username 2</h5>
                    <small class="text-muted float-right">timestamp</small>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div>
                      This is a third message
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      ASNDJKASJDAJDKLAJLADSAJLKASDJLAKSJDKLSAJDLKAJKALDJKLJDLADJLASJDLKSAJDASJDLASDASDASDASDASA
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <hr class="w-100">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <!-- message block -->
                  <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <div style="height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: black"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <h5 class="text-danger float-left">Username</h5>
                    <small class="text-muted float-right">timestamp</small>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div>
                      This is a single message
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      This is another single message
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <hr class="w-100">
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- end messages box -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-2 d-none d-lg-block">
              Users bar, gets pushed under first column before disappearing when one of messages is too long
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just open it in another window and resize it to a smaller size.

Comment: Please [read the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#responsive-classes). There is no `-xs` in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Oh, I got used to bs3 and thought the column classes remained the same. Good to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you use Bootstrap 4. 
Instead of `col-xs-1` use `col-1`, instead of `col`, use `col-11` (or `col-10` `offset-1` to make distance between avatar and message)

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Card header
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <!-- full-width column for message box -->
              <div class="container-fluid" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden">
                <!-- start of messages box -->
                <div class="row">
                  <!-- message block -->
                  <div class="col-1">
                    <div style="height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: black"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-10 offset-1">
                    <h5 class="text-danger float-left">Username</h5>
                    <small class="text-muted float-right">timestamp</small>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div>
                      This is a single message
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      This is another single message
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <hr class="w-100">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-1">
                    <div style="height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: black"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-10 offset-1">
                    <h5 class="text-danger float-left">Username 2</h5>
                    <small class="text-muted float-right">timestamp</small>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div>
                      This is a third message
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      ASNDJKASJDAJDKLAJLADSAJLKASDJLAKSJDKLSAJDLKAJKALDJKLJDLADJLASJDLKSAJDASJDLASDASDASDASDASA
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <hr class="w-100">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <!-- message block -->
                  <div class="col-1">
                    <div style="height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: black"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-10 offset-1">
                    <h5 class="text-danger float-left">Username</h5>
                    <small class="text-muted float-right">timestamp</small>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div>
                      This is a single message
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      This is another single message
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <hr class="w-100">
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- end messages box -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-2 d-none d-lg-block">
              Users bar, gets pushed under first column before disappearing when one of messages is too long
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, but the problem of the col-2 on the right side being pushed under instead of disappearing is still there. Any idea how to fix this? I'm guessing it's because of the left column being just "col", but how to do it so that on smaller screens the right column disappears and left one takes the whole grid?

Comment: @hazelnutek you want on small screen: columns with avatar on the whole size of the row, columns with message text to disappear, right?

Comment: I've fixed it by just changing the "message box" column to be ```col col-lg-10``` and it seems to work ok, on large screens it's col-10 + right column is col-2. On smaller it gets automatically resized. Now I don't see the problem of users column being pushed under the message box. Thanks!